# What if refresh token is lost?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am implementing OAuth 2.0 in Laravel5 for one of my web services project to protect my api endpoints.
I am using password and refresh token grants.Everything is working fine, but I am wondering what if my refresh token is lost during its transaction from server to device, like if internet is disconnected and device doesn't get any refresh token so how it will generate a new access token to perform actions.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to login again? (user credentials)

Comment: I am using Oauth to authenticate device not user so there is no specific thing that I an de-register. Moreover I am not allowing any device to create more then one session on server. So what will I do if refresh token is lost by any way ?

Comment: I am experiecing the loss of tokens (devices in low reception relying on mobile data connection). I am considering implementing handshare that actives the refresh token, before the old one is removed. (Refresh (T0) -> new Token(T1) (disbled); Activate(T0:T1) -> expire old token (T0))